# INNER JOIN ON multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm sure you guys'll see why I'm getting a syntax error. It should also be clear what I'm trying to accomplish. Would appreciate what changes I need to make without deviating too far from the current code.

```
 SELECT [Worker Listing.Fname], [Worker Listing.Lname], [Desired Job Titles.JobTitle]
 FROM [Worker Listing]
 INNER JOIN [Desired Job Titles]  
 ON Worker Listing.JobID1=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 OR Worker Listing.JobID2=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 OR Worker Listing.JobID3=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 OR Worker Listing.JobID4=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 OR Worker Listing.JobID5=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 OR Worker Listing.JobID6=Desired Job Titles.JobID
 ORDER BY [Worker Listing.LName];
```

Comment: put [] on your on clause ex [Worker Listing].JobID1=[Desired Job Titles].JobID

Comment: Use the query wizard. MS Access is very fussy about brackets on joins and spaces in names.

Comment: Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not for asking 'will you fix this for me'. You can better ask: 'How can I best ... '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote your table name `Desired Job Titles` everywhere in your query as `[Desired Job Titles]`, same on `[Worker Listing]`:

```
SELECT [Worker Listing].[Fname], [Worker Listing].[Lname], [Desired Job Titles].[JobTitle]
FROM [Worker Listing]
INNER JOIN [Desired Job Titles]  
ON [Worker Listing].JobID1=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
OR [Worker Listing].JobID2=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
OR [Worker Listing].JobID3=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
OR [Worker Listing].JobID4=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
OR [Worker Listing].JobID5=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
OR [Worker Listing].JobID6=[Desired Job Titles].JobID
ORDER BY [Worker Listing].[LName];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Desired Job Titles.JobTitle] needs to be [Desired Job Titles].[JobTitle]